# Issue rendering JPQL custom query results into a JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have an entity with the following named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllGarbage", query = "SELECT g.filename, g.description, g.uploadDate FROM Garbage g;")
```

The problem is that i want to pass that result to a dataTable to render, and i recieve NumberFormatException. I dont understand why because there are no numbers anywhere.

This is how the rest of the program looks like:

-The EJB that executes the query

```
@Stateless(name = "ejbs/SearchEJB")
public class SearchEJB implements ISearchEJB {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


public List<Garbage> findAllGarbage() {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllGarbage");    
    List<Garbage> tmpGarbage = query.getResultList();
    return tmpGarbage;
}
```

-The part of the JSF that displays the tableData:

```
<p:dataTable var="garbage" value="#{resultsController.allGarbage}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">         

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Filename" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.filename}" />
             </p:column> 

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Description" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.description}" />  
             </p:column> 

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Upload date" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.uploadDate}" /> 
             </p:column>                
    </p:dataTable>
```

-The managed bean that interacts with the JSF page:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ResultsController {

@EJB
private ISearchEJB searchEJB;

private Garbage garbage;

public List<Garbage> getAllGarbage() {
    return searchEJB.findAllGarbage();
}

public Garbage getGarbage() {
    return garbage;
}

public void setGarbage(Garbage garbage) {
    this.garbage = garbage;
}
```

The error says:

> WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "filename"

I dont understand what is wrong with the file name.

------------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------

I changed the JSF to this, and now i dont see the error. I see tha table data but empty:

```
<p:dataTable var="garbage" value="#{resultsController.allGarbage}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">         

        <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Filename" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{garbage[4]}" />
         </p:column> 

        <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Description" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{garbage[3]}" />  
         </p:column> 

        <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Upload date" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{garbage[6]}" /> 
         </p:column>                
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that a query such as

```
SELECT g.filename, g.description, g.uploadDate FROM Garbage
```

returns an `Object[]` with filename, description and uploadDate as its elements.

If you want to access them as object properties (as you do in JSF), you need to query for the full object instead:

```
SELECT g FROM Garbage g
```

Comment: That is not an option because it will retrive also the file itself. And that slows down the preformance. Each file can be few megabites. I need somehow to exclude from the query a variable called file of type byte[]

Comment: @sfrj: Then you need to use array indexes instead of field names in the view (I'm not sure how would it work in JSF).

Comment: My idea was to try to do what you said: SELECT g FROM Garbage g and try to add something like EXCEPT g.file But that didnt work.  I dont know haw array indexes work. Is there any other option? I just need the Garbage object without the attribute file.

Comment: @sfrj: Have you just tried to write `#{garbage[0]}` instead of `#{garbage.filename}` and so on?

Comment: This one should work. You would for compile time consistency also like to replace `List<Garbage>` by `List<Object[]>` in your bean code btw.

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly there is just one mistake in my Uptade. I should call garbace[0], garbace[1] and garbace[2] instead of garbace[3] garbace[4] garbace[6].

Thank you